# Logical 'or' operator within a Numpy where function

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I want to set the amount field to be equal to the field Delta Amount whenever i see the type renewal upgrade or term change / resigning, however using the logical OR operator generates an error. Similarly is there a more slick way of doing this? Say I had more values I want to check, is there a way to do it such as how SQL allows for IN (list here) instead of needing to OR together every value? Code below. Thanks.

```
sddr_pipeline['Amount'] = np.where((sddr_pipeline['Type'] == 'Renewal - Upgrade' 
| sddr_pipeline['Type'] == 'Term change/Re-signing')
, sddr_pipeline['Delta Amount'], sddr_pipeline['Amount'])
```

This code returns the error: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

Above is what I tried based on some Numpy examples online.

Comment: numpy.logical_or

Comment: And if you're working with Pandas, you might want to use Pandas' `where`.

Comment: What is `sddr_pipeline`?  dataframe or structured numpy array?  If the latter, what's the `dtype`?  When combining boolean expressions use   `(...)|(....)` etc.  That is, enclose with (), and use `|` or `&`.

Comment: @FrankYellin why can I not use '|' as a logical or here?

Comment: *" is there a way to do it such as how SQL allows for IN (list here)** Yes, `isin`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

Comment: You can use '|' with multiple conditions; each condition must be in ( ) parentheses because of precedence. Also note numpy .where provides for if True / if False values whereas Pandas .where actions change if False (see also .mask which changes if True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example I can't test this, but I can suggest a fix:

```
sddr_pipeline['Amount'] = 
np.where(((sddr_pipeline['Type'] == 'Renewal - Upgrade') 
| (sddr_pipeline['Type'] == 'Term change/Re-signing'))
, sddr_pipeline['Delta Amount'], 
sddr_pipeline['Amount'])
```

Each argument of the `where` is evaluated first, and then passed to `where` function (standard python practice).  For a complex expression like this it would be a good idea to check them individually

```
((sddr_pipeline['Type'] == 'Renewal - Upgrade') 
| (sddr_pipeline['Type'] == 'Term change/Re-signing'))
```

The extra () are important to establish the order of evaluation.

Comment: This worked thank you! I see you need each OR clause wrapped in parenthesis not the entire section, that makes sense.